# How to insert a blank row at the first position inside spinner using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written a program to load data from sqlite database into my spinner , so when i start an activity adapter directly loads the data into the spinner and automatically an event fires without touching anything , how i want is an empty spinner and when i select an item from spinner from dropdown then only certain event should occur.

```
cursor = listHelper.getAccountName(String
                        .valueOf(selected_item_1));
                int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
                String[] from = new String[] { DbListHelper.ACCOUNT_NAME };
                final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter5 = new 
                        SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from,
                        to) {
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
                        View v = super.getView(position, convertView,
                                parent);

                        ((TextView) v).setTextSize(18);
                        ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color
                                .parseColor("#1C689C"));
                        return v;
                    }

                    public View getDropDownView(int position, View 
                            convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {

                        View v = null;

                        if (position == 0) {
                            TextView tv = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                            tv.setHeight(0);
                            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            v = tv;
                        } else {

                            v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, 
                                parent);
                        }

                        ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                        parent.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                        return v;
                    }

                };

                adapter5.setDropDownViewResource
                (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerAccountName.setAdapter(adapter5);
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do it ?
Thank You

Comment: Do you mean like adding an empty element to your Cursor ? that way you'll have an empty first element. is that what you want ?

Comment: yes adding an empty item to my adapter so that i can select an item from the spinner, because the item which i want to select once the activity is started gets loaded automatically and fires an event on its own

Comment: That is not the best way to handle spinners, but in your case, I thins you can just add an empty row on database and be done with it ;)

Comment: sir what if the data is coming from a webservice , it wont have an empty record , so i think its not an ideal solution to insert an empty record into the database

Comment: you want to insert a first item is empty ,before Your web service data,loading  in Spinner ?